# Can not display the data becuase Power BI can not determine the relationship between two or more fields

Tags: powerbi

I have added 2 separate SharePoint lists inside my Power BI desktop, as follow:-

[image]

now there is not any relation between the 2 tables. and i built 2 tabs inside Power BI >> each table to show the data in a table format >> then i publish the reports.

but when i access the reports inside my workspace >> one tab is working well , while the other is raising this error:-

[image]

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Possible fix 1: Ensure only using fields from one table in visual**

I'm guessing that you accidentally picked up a field on both tables. It should fail in Power BI Desktop too.

Check the field pane for the failing visual. Make sure only one table is being used. This will cause the error you describe:

[image: 2 tables in use]

**Possible Fix 2: Rebuild the table**

Often it is easier to just rebuild a visual than try to figure out what went wrong. I would just try to rebuild the failing visual from scratch. Don't copy from the other visual.

**Possible Fix 3: Find the culprit**

While fix 2 often works, I would still want to know why! I would use the [Measure Killer](https://en.brunner.bi/measurekiller) External Tool, which is great at identifying every field used in a report, including things like filters and conditional formatting. If it isn't the obvious problem in Fix #1, this should find what is causing the problem.